# Exit strategy on cointegrated pairs trading

Tags: pairs-trading, cointegration

I'm looking for guidance on an exit strategy when using pairs trading & cointegration. I'm able to find two cointegrated pairs, I then enter the trade however once in the trade I found the pairs lose their cointegration (pvalue > 0.05) and then become cointegrated again. Originally I was using the zscore = 0 however I found when the pair lost their cointegration and the became cointegrated again then exiting at zscore = 0 wound up with a losing trade. I'm currently using the stop loss (so with each tick I calculate my percentage PnL) and exit on 0.5% but this is also not proving fruitful, I suspect the stop loss is too tight. I'm looking for guidance on strategies I can use.

I'm using crypto's on the 30M timeframe.

Here are some I'm toying with:

1. Exit at x% stop loss. But the question here is what %age should I use? I'm using 0.5% and think it's a bit tight. When I enter at 0.5% my take profit is around 0.5% as well so it's a 1:1 ratio. But I'm finding I enter a trade as the zscore/pairs are diverging and it hits the 0.5% then reverts.
2. Exit at zscore = 0. However as mentioned above what do I do if the PnL is negative and the pairs lose their cointegration? Some reading I've done says one should exit when the zscore is zero however I've seen pairs go in and out of cointegration so don't want to exit too early.
3. Something else? I'm using a combination of a sliding stop loss, zscore = 0 and take profit at x%

Please help.

Comment: Hi: I realize that you're new to this list but, without intending to be rude, I doubt that your question will get answered for two reasons. 1) There are so many factors involved which makes it difficult to give a useful answer. 2) If anyone has experience with what you're doing and has figured something useful and relevant to your questions, they most likely would prefer to keep it to themselves.

Comment: I guess you can simply backtest all options you've just listed thoroughly, so that you could have a better view of each. It seems to me many of your questions can be answered with backtest results, but now you only have some observations that could be quite subjective and biased. Run tests, think about what happened and reasons behind, and improve.